# What is the best way to read from flash and store in a buffer using C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bootloader

I have my APP image in hexadecimal format which will be downloaded to flash by my bootloader. Before that i have to compare the checksum and this checksum function or CRC function used on the other end was to add all bytes. So I want to read the 512 bytes starting at the address 0x2000 of flash block and store them into a buffer so that I can use this while calculating the checksum by adding all the bytes and also during writing the updated image to the flash. I meant to say a C program reading the bytes(512 Bytes) from a location in flash and storing them in a buffer. What is the best way? Using memcpy? or pointers? or arrays? Thanks in advance. Can I do in the following way?

```
void readBytes(uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t byteCount)
{
    uint32_t currentBytesRead = 0;

    for(currentBytesRead=0;currentBytesRead<byteCount;currentBytesRead++)
    {
        buffer[currentBytesRead] = (char*)APPstartAddress;

        APPstartAddress++;
    }
}
```

I used linker description file and it has my

```
m_interrupts    (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0xC0   /*192 Bytes*/
  m_cfmprotrom  (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00002400, LENGTH = 0x10   /*16 Bytes*/
/* m_flash (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x00002411, LENGTH = 0x400 1024 Bytes reserve space for reading and writing into flash*/
  m_text        (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00002800, LENGTH = 128K - 0x800
  /*reserving the last 2KB of flash by subtracting those bytes (0x800) from m_text segment*/
  m_data         (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x1FFFF000, LENGTH = 16K
```

Comment: what have you tried?  We are not a 'free' coding service.  We will help you with problems you have with YOUR code.

Comment: is your app linked for the final location?  Did you use a linker command file, etc?

Comment: By "hexadecimal format", do you mean Intel hex file, or what? What checksum are you on about? Intel hex use quick & dirty checksum, not proper CRC. Do you mean some sort of checksum in your application? How are we supposed to know how that checksum is calculated?

Comment: I am doing some sort of checksum in my application

Comment: the 'intel hex' format ('S' records) is not executable. how does your code handle the extraction of the data portion of each record?  If it were me, I would not change the variable that contains the start address of where the code is to be saved.

Comment: please post the linker command file as part of the question, not as a (mostly unreadable) comment

Comment: Can I use memcpy?

Comment: yes / not / maybe. What CPU platform? Some procesors have idependent memory spaces for flash/ram, so simple memcpy dont work.

Comment: ARM cortex m0 controller

Comment: Your question states that the data is in flash, in intel hex format (very wasteful) and that it fits into a 512 byte of flash/ram.   Given the criteria, your app must be very small.  Extracting the 'meat' from a Intel Hex file, before placing into flash, would be much better

Comment: OT:  a checksum is just the some of all the bytes.  a CRC is cyclic redundancy checksum which uses exclusive OR operations, bit shifting, etc.  Which are you actually using?

Comment: checksum i.e., sum of all the bytes

Comment: what is the declaration of the variable: `APPstartAddress`?

Comment: Start address of my application in the flash.. 0x2000

Comment: Depending on the system design, the flash might not be mapped into memory at all.  There is a type of flash that is accessed via a serial bus, that you have to read block by block into RAM to be able to 'see' it.